# angular cli showing error while launching server

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and still learning it and this is project I have created but I am unable to launch the server. It is giving me the below two errors. I have launched the server many times before but now it is suddenly giving me these two errors. This is my project on github:  https://github.com/NoamaanMulla/angular.git

```
Error: ./src/app/website/products/products.component.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: F:\Training\Projects\practice\src\app\website\products\products.component.ts is missing from 
the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' 
property.
at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile 
(F:\Training\Projects\practice\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:951:23)
at F:\Training\Projects\practice\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:43:31
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

Error: ./src/app/website/products/productsample/productsample.component.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: 
F:\Training\Projects\practice\src\app\website\products\productsample\productsample.component.ts is 
missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 
'include' property.
at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile 
(F:\Training\Projects\practice\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:951:23)
at F:\Training\Projects\practice\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:43:31
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went through your code, this issue generally happens if  one of you imports have capitalized UserClass

Change in **`app.routing.module`**

**`From`**

```
import { ProductsComponent } from './website/Products/Products.component';
import { ProductsampleComponent } from './website/Products/Productsample/Productsample.component';
```

**`To`**

```
import { ProductsComponent } from './website/products/products.component';
import { ProductsampleComponent } from './website/products/productsample/productsample.component';
```